# Некорректно работает коллизия на android, хотя в редакторе unity, всё нормально

Tags: android, c#, unity3d

Вот собственно перегруженный метод коллизии:

```
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
        {
            if (!Logic.Instance.GameOver)
            {
                if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Point")
                {
                    ++Logic.Instance.Score;
                    Destroy(collision.gameObject);
                // именно эта часть не работает. То есть, при столкновении, 
//об'ект должен уничтожатся, в этом случае, инструкции андроида почему-то //игнорируют данный участок кода... Или может дело в чём то другом
                }
                else if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Platform")
                    isGround = true;
                else if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Block")
                {
                    Logic.Instance.LabelToStart.transform.position = new Vector3
                        (Logic.Instance.LabelToStart.transform.position.x,
                        Logic.Instance.LabelToStart.transform.position.y, 0.0f); // print label tap to start
                    Logic.Instance.GameOver = true;
                    GameObject[] blocks = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Block");
                    GameObject[] points = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Point");
                    foreach (GameObject it in blocks)
                        Destroy(it.gameObject);
                    foreach (GameObject it in points)
                    Destroy(it.gameObject);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Решил данный вопрос, путём написания еще одного скрипта, который реагирует на самого игрока, а не наоборот. Но, всё ровно хотел бы узнать, почему данный способ некорретен, ведь редактор unity его воспринимает!

Comment: вы пробовали посмотреть логи во время игры? Соберите Debug build. Там будет включена консоль и ошибка, если она есть,  появится в ней. Возможно, проблема даже не в этом месте - сама логика игры может отваливаться гораздо раньше. Дело в том, что в билде у unity может несколько отличаться порядок запуска скриптов. Т.е. порядок Awake=>Start соблюдается так же, но вот порядок внутри них может отличаться от редактора.